# Not able to take to an Intent properly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've to check whether the user entered code is valid with the database code. If yes, it should populate all the details from firebase database to all the fields in the layout. Otherwise, It should take back to Home Page giving a user a toast that he isn't authorized.

The problem is, even if the user entered code matches the database code it is taking me to `HomePage`. How can I solve this ? Can anyone guide me.

Code in my `onCreate` method:

```
inputCodesReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      enteredUserCode = (String) ds.child("code").getValue();
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});

familyListReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      String key = (String) ds.getKey();
      DatabaseReference keyReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("familylist").child(key);
      keyReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          final String code = dataSnapshot.child("code").getValue(String.class);
          String family = dataSnapshot.child("family").getValue(String.class);
          String father = dataSnapshot.child("fatherName").getValue(String.class);
          String mother = dataSnapshot.child("motherName").getValue(String.class);

          for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.child("children").getChildren()) {
            String child = childSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if (code.equals(enteredUserCode))
              children.add(child);
          }

          if (code.equals(enteredUserCode)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "[FINAL CHECK IN ACTIVITY] Database Code: " + code);
            Log.d(TAG, "[FINAL CHECK IN ACTIVITY] User Input code: " + enteredUserCode);
            familyName = family;
            fatherName = father;
            motherName = mother;
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            welcomeMessage.setText("Welcome " + familyName + " family!");
            fatherRadioButton.setText(fatherName);
            motherRadioButton.setText(motherName);
          } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
          }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
        }
      }); // [Key Reference]

    } // END of for Loop
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
  }
}); // [familyList Database Reference]


//[CHECK IN]
checkinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      if (fatherRadioButton.isChecked()) {
        checkIn = new CheckIn(familyName, fatherName, null, checkInTime, childrenToDatabase);
      } else {
        checkIn = new CheckIn(familyName, null, motherName, checkInTime, childrenToDatabase);
      }
      checkInCheckOutDatabaseReference.push().setValue(checkIn);
      Intent intent = new Intent(CheckInFinalActivity.this, HomePage.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      Toast.makeText(CheckInFinalActivity.this, "Check in Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: are you sure you're not calling `startActivity` anywhere else? This Firebase listener is an async call. Adding more parts of the code would help to diagnose.

Comment: check the read and write permission for the user

Comment: Problem isn't about reading or writing. Its about taking a user to a proper Intent @siva

Comment: Yes, I'm using `startActivity()` in checkIn button's `onClick` method. I added my onCreate method code. Please check the above updated question.  @KrishnaKalubandi

Comment: Alright, If I understand the flow correctly, the user enters a `code` and then clicks on the `checkInButton`. Then you want to validate the `code` and then redirect to an activity based on the correctness of the `code`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. I have 2 Activities. One is `CheckIn` activity where it will prompt user to enter code. There I've put the EditText with type `numberPassword`. If a user enters the code and when clicked `done` on keypad It will take to next Intent `CheckInFinal` activity where the data of that particular user based on code gets populated to the respective fields. Hope I'm clear to you @KrishnaKalubandi

Comment: Got it. Please check the answer and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

The lines where you get `enteredUserCode` inside the `onDataChange` method are executed whenever the `DataSnapshot` is retrieved from `firebase` as this call is `asynchronous` in nature.

Hence, the `enteredUserCode` might not be available for the `familyListReference` at that moment. To make sure that the `enteredUserCode` is available, you need to move the `familyListReference's` listener inside the `inputCodeReference` `onDataChange` method.

Here's the modified code.

```
inputCodesReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      enteredUserCode = (String) ds.child("code").getValue();
    }
    familyListReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          String key = (String) ds.getKey();
          DatabaseReference keyReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("familylist").child(key);
          keyReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              final String code = dataSnapshot.child("code").getValue(String.class);
              String family = dataSnapshot.child("family").getValue(String.class);
              String father = dataSnapshot.child("fatherName").getValue(String.class);
              String mother = dataSnapshot.child("motherName").getValue(String.class);

              for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.child("children").getChildren()) {
                String child = childSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if (code.equals(enteredUserCode))
                  children.add(child);
              }

              if (code.equals(enteredUserCode)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "[FINAL CHECK IN ACTIVITY] Database Code: " + code);
                Log.d(TAG, "[FINAL CHECK IN ACTIVITY] User Input code: " + enteredUserCode);
                familyName = family;
                fatherName = father;
                motherName = mother;
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                welcomeMessage.setText("Welcome " + familyName + " family!");
                fatherRadioButton.setText(fatherName);
                motherRadioButton.setText(motherName);
              } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
              }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
            }
          }); // [Key Reference]

        } // END of for Loop
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
      }
    }); // [familyList Database Reference]
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});

//[CHECK IN]
checkinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      if (fatherRadioButton.isChecked()) {
        checkIn = new CheckIn(familyName, fatherName, null, checkInTime, childrenToDatabase);
      } else {
        checkIn = new CheckIn(familyName, null, motherName, checkInTime, childrenToDatabase);
      }
      checkInCheckOutDatabaseReference.push().setValue(checkIn);
      Intent intent = new Intent(CheckInFinalActivity.this, HomePage.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      Toast.makeText(CheckInFinalActivity.this, "Check in Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
});
```

This ensures the `enteredUserCode` is ready and available for the next actions.

Now that you have a single method, the code can be further simplified by getting a `rootFirebaseInstance` instead of adding two listeners. It depends on how you have organized your `json` schema.

Comment: This didn't work out for me. When i added this, the looping goes on and the app is getting hanged. :(

Comment: I slightly changed the code. Did you try with that latest one?

Comment: Can i give you this source code through github? will you be able to review once. That would be great.

Comment: Sure give me the link

Comment: Here you go ! Please refer this [link](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/TAB/blob/master/CheckInFinalActivity.java)

Comment: I edited my answer 8 mins ago. Please use the latest snippet. It should work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145917/discussion-between-pc-and-krishna-kalubandi).

Comment: can you please come to Discussion room if possible.